# Batch file to copy and rename files with folder name

Tags: batch-file, copy, rename

I have a folder that contains hundreds of movie sub-folders each of which contains a couple of movies and several jpgs. Each movie sub-folder and one jpg in that folder have been given the name of a movie (ie. Folder Name: `The Matrix` and Image Names: `The Matrix.jpg`, `backdrop.jpg`, `fanart.jpg`). I would like to make a copy of each of the jpgs with the same name as the folder, name these copies `folder.jpg`, and place them in the same folder.

I found this script but couldn't figure out how to tweak it for my situation as it assumes there is only one jpg in the folder.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s *.jpg') do Echo COPY "%%~dpnxF" "%%~dpF\folder.jpg"
echo Done
Pause
```

Comment: If you name 2 files folder.jpg and put them in the same folder, the last file copied will overwrite the existing one, you'd need to come up with a unique name for each file in order to retain them.  In your example, even if you changed the hardcoded file name to a variable, you'd need to also come up with a way to make the name unique to retain each file...  Maybe something like <folder>-<original file name>.  Unfortunately, my brain is fried from work so I can't give an actual working example.

Comment: To rephrase that - you can't put three files in the folder with the same name.  Have we misunderstood what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    set "whereToStart=d:\movies"

    for /d /r "%whereToStart%" %%f in (*) do (
        if exist "%%~ff\%%~nxf.jpg" copy /y "%%~ff\%%~nxf.jpg" "%%~ff\folder.jpg" 
    )
```

For each folder, if it contains a .jpg file with the same name as the directory, copy this file as folder.jpg inside the same directory. Aditional check can be added to avoid not needed copies, checking for presence of the target file

```
@echo off
    set "whereToStart=d:\movies"

    for /d /r "%whereToStart%" %%f in (*) do (
        if exist "%%~ff\%%~nxf.jpg" if not exist "%%~ff\folder.jpg" (
            copy "%%~ff\%%~nxf.jpg" "%%~ff\folder.jpg" 
        )
    )
```